# Is Sherlock a real name?

Tags: meaning

Is Sherlock a real name? Are there any people named Sherlock in real life?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the popularity of proper names, not the English language as such

Comment: People can get creative with names. There is no rule, beyond human sensibility, as to what can and what can not be used as a first name. Although there may have been a court case that declined to recognize the validity of a certain string of characters as a first name. I could name my child *Vfekfddg* and pronounce it like *Smith* and that would be "real". Google "unusual first names" and you will get quite a list of examples.

Comment: English *usage* seems to me to include how English is used in naming people. Perhaps the question could be rewarded a bit to better fit the site.

Comment: It's spelled "Raymond Luxury-Yacht," but it's pronounced THROATWARBLER MANGROVE! (Monty Python) :-)

Comment: english is so stupid when it is pronounced differently than spelled...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there have been people named Sherlock.

According to the [Social Security Administration's](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/limits.html) data, Sherlock has never been one of the thousand most common names used in the United States. In that data, 5 males in the US were born in 1930 named Sherlock, 7 in 1949, 7 in 1955, 5 in 1978, 6 in 2012, and 8 in 2014. No females are listed. The data doesn't include any names that don't have at least five occurrences in a given year.

Wikipedia has articles on several people with the [surname Sherlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock), including English church leader William Sherlock born in 1641 and pianist James Sherlock born in 1983.

[ESPN](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/story/82166.html) has information on how Sir Arthur Conan Doyle's cricket career inspired the Christian name of Sherlock Holmes:

> [Jonathan Forster, of Congleton] suggests that the name Sherlock was derived from two Notts players of the 1880s, the bowler T F Shacklock and the wicketkeeper Mordecai Sherwin, the scorebook often recording c Sherwin b Shacklock.

Comment: So you're saying yes?